# Windows Task Scheduler vbs file fails (but runs fine manually)

Tags: windows, excel, vbscript, office-automation, event-viewer

I'm using windows task scheduler to run the below script file on the event of an excel crash (application event 1000).  If I run the script manually, the excel file 'E:\Test.xlsm' opens as excepted.  However, when called from the task manager (on the event of an excel application crash) excel doesn't open.  At least, there is no instance of excel open when i later check.  From the event viewer window i can see that my vbs file is indeed called, but for some reason it isn't opening excel.

What can possibly be causing the different behavior between my running the script manually (double clicking on it) and when it is called from the windows task manager?

I'm using windows 2008R2 and excel 2010 (32-bit).

Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

ExcelRestart

Sub ExcelRestart()    
  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False  
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\Test.xlsm")
  xlApp.visible = True 
  xlBook.activate
  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing
End sub
```

Comment: Maybe the credentials used to run the task are not allowed to access the file or to execute excel

Comment: i'm running as administrator.  or, do you mean some other type of credentials?

Comment: You are administrator, but your task is started under some credentials not necessarily the same.

Comment: Is `E:\` a local drive or mapped network?

Comment: E is local, but is on a aws virtual machine.

Comment: @MC ND.  Under task scheduler i have the box 'Run with highest privileges' checked.  Are there some other credentials i should be aware of?